# How to expand trimmed textBlock

Tags: c#, xaml, windows-8, microsoft-metro

I have a metro application on C#.
And i have a big text.
I need to display this text trimmed on textblock, but when user click on it, textblock is expanded and display full text.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Normally my first question would be what have you tried? Some quick direction though (at least a simple solution with xaml only anyway) would be to use `TextTrimming="WordEllipsis"` for your trimming, then use an `EventTrigger` to catch the `Click` event with a `ChangePropertyAction` to switch back to `TextTrimming="none"` and probably at the same time also initiate `TextWrapping="Wrap"` to fulfill your requirements. If you need an example I can whip one up for you but the concept is provided here. Hope this helps.

**update**

Something like this;

```
  <TextBlock 
        Text="Yada Yada Yada Blah Blah Blah This is a bunch of text stuff blah blah blah." 
        TextTrimming="WordEllipsis" TextWrapping="NoWrap" MaxWidth="100">
            <i:Interaction.Triggers>
               <i:EventTrigger EventName="Click">
                    <ei:ChangePropertyAction PropertyName="TextTrimming"
                                             Value="None" />
                    <ei:ChangePropertyAction PropertyName="TextWrapping"
                                             Value="Wrap" />
                    <ei:ChangePropertyAction PropertyName="MaxWidth"
                                             Value="150"/>                                                   
               </i:EventTrigger>
            </i:Interaction.Triggers>
   </TextBlock>
```

Comment: I understand You, but i have trouble with code. If You can, please give me example.

Comment: See updated answer for concept example, will require the interactivity/interactions namespaces for the triggers of course.

Comment: Actually you know what? I'm retarded and didn't even pay attention to your tags. `Triggers` aren't much help in Win8, you'll have to use `VisualStateManager` instead for it. I'll make something that route when I get some more free time. Too much time in SL land has rotted my brain... :/